# Open link in new tab on image click in angular without popup blocker

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have setup ng-click on a image in my web page. In the ng-click handler, I use

```
    ServiceData.getProductDetails(product).then(function(data) {
        $scope.url = data;
            var win = window.open($scope.url, '_blank');
            win.focus();
    });

    getProductDetails: function(product) {
        var promiseProductDetails;
        if (productDetailsArr[product.id] == undefined) {
            var ajaxUrl = productsByIDarray[product.id]['detailsview'];
            try {

                // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
                promiseProductDetails = $http.get(ajaxUrl).then(function(response) {
                    return response;
                });
            } catch(err) {
            }

            // Return the promise to the controller
            return promiseProductDetails;
        } else {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(productDetailsArr[product.id][url]);
            return deferred.promise;
        }

    }
```

So the click initiates an ajax call to fetch the URL where user should go (the target url is dynamic). I have made the ajax call as sync using angular promise. This results in the web browser treating it as untrusted and blocks the popup. I don't want to enclose the img tag with anchor a tag in html. Do I have any option available to avoid the popup blocker?

Comment: What is the rest of the code. Is there something else that is causing a delay?

Comment: yes there is ajax call involved. I have made it sync request using promise but still hitting popup blocker. I have added the full code in my question

Comment: That is your issue, there is a delay and the delay means pop up blocker blocks it.

Comment: so to avoid the popup blocker, I should cache that response of ajax call in JS before the user clicks on the image and then window.open will bypass popup blocker. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the ajax call to an earlier point of user interaction with page is the solution for this.